# Python - Tkinter how to add space between two ttk.Labelframe(s)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm sure i'm missing something here, but I haven't been able to add a gap or space between two ttk.Labelframe objects when they have been placed next to each other using the Grid() geometry manager (ref pic below).

[image]

A simple representation of the structure of my code (pseudo) is as follows:

```
Root()
    mainframe = ttk.Frame()
         frame1 = ttk.Labelframe()
         frame1.Grid(row=0, column=0)
         frame2 = ttk.Labelframe()
         frame2.Grid(row=0, column=1)
```

I have tried `mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)` and `mainframe.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)` to no avail (however this works for other widgets inside those frames). I have also tried adding more `padding` to `mainframe` but this only adds padding around the inside of `mainframe`. frame1 and frame2, not between them.

I have probably missed a keyword or property somewhere that will do the trick but i'm yet to find it. Remember, i'm using themed tkinter widgets (ttk) so not all keywords tk widgets have apply to the ttk widgets.

Thanks in advance all,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it just typical that you find the answer you're looking for only after posting the question . . .

It seems it was a keyword in `mainframe.columnconfigure()` that i missed. The keyword is `pad` funnily enough (-.-). i.e.: `mainframe.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1, pad=5)` will configure columns 0 through 1 to each have a weighting of 1 (if stretched) and an additional padding of 5 pixels that will be added above the
largest cell in those columns, resulting in space between the frames.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, there is also a padx and pady option on the grid command itself: `the_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)` -  Bryan Oakley

Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: There is also a `padx` and `pady` option on the `grid` command itself: `the_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)`